# dataTaskWithRequest in a function (soap)

Tags: ios, swift, soap

I'm doing a SOAP call, but when I'm debugging, but when I do a task.resume() it doesn't go into dataTaskWithRequest, at first time, so I continue the debugging and it's only at the end that it goes into dataTaskWithRequest without call, I don't understand why it does this, it is because I'm using it into a function ? code:

```
func soapCall(fonction:String, messageSoap:String) -> Int{


    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {

        let soapRequest = AEXMLDocument()
        let attributes = ["xmlns:SOAP-ENV" : "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "xmlns:ns1" : "urn:contactFile", "xmlns:xsd" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xmlns:xsi" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xmlns:SOAP-ENC" : "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle" : "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"]
        let envelope = soapRequest.addChild(name: "SOAP-ENV:Envelope", attributes: attributes)
        let body = envelope.addChild(name: "SOAP-ENV:Body")
        let sendLead = body.addChild(name: "ns1:"+fonction)
        sendLead.addChild(name: "xml", attributes: ["xsi:type" : "xsd:string"], value: messageSoap)

        let soapMessage = soapRequest.xmlString

        let messageSoapMinify = minify(soapMessage)




        //        URL Soap
        let urlString = soapServiceURL
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

        //        Taille SoapMessage
        let msgLength = String(messageSoapMinify.characters.count)

        //        Soap Login
        let username = soapUsername
        let password = soapPassword
        let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
        let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

        //        Requete Soap
        theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        theRequest.addValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
        theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        theRequest.addValue("urn:ResponseAction", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
        theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        theRequest.addValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        //        print("Request is \(theRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields!)")

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(theRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response Login: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print("Body Login: \(strData)")
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error Login: " + error!.description)
            }
            let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
            if(self.success == "1"){
                self.successSoap = 1
            }

        })


        task.resume()
    }


    return successSoap
}
```

I receive successfully the data in my database, but here they're an error with task.resume() it don't go immediately in dataTaskWithRequest().

EDIT:

```
func soapCall(fonction:String, messageSoap:String, completion: (result: Int)->()){
    ...
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(theRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response Login: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print("Body Login: \(strData)")
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error Login: " + error!.description)
            }
            let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
            if(self.success == "1"){
                self.successSoap = 1
            }

        })


        task.resume()
    }
    completion(result: successSoap)
}
```

The call here:

```
    var statutEnvoie = 0

    serviceSoap.soapCall(fonctionSoap, messageSoap: messageSoapSendLead){ (result) in
        if result == 1 {
            print("SoapCall OK !!!!!!!!!!!!!")
            statutEnvoie = 1
        } else {
            print("SoapCall PAS BON !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
            statutEnvoie = 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: *You can't return from an asynchronous function!* You have to use callbacks, often named "completion handlers" in Swift. Have a look at [this recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36036593/2227743), or one of the many, many other ones in my answers or in SO.

Comment: @EricD. I have an completion handler in dataTaskWithRequest

Comment: The completion in dataTaskWithRequest *is for the data, response, error of dataTaskWithRequest*, it's not *your* callback. I'm talking about *adding* a callback to get back the data this one fetches. Like in the example I've given. Or like plenty of my recent answers.

Comment: @EricD. Look my edit I have the same error :( then

Comment: Eh, you're almost there. Your completion handler should be in the same scope as the task, I mean *inside*  the task. Put it just after the `if(self.success == "1") {}` block for example, it should work.

Comment: @EricD. can I do two times completion(result: successSoap) ? In the if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork == true and the else ?

Comment: You can use the completion at any location where it makes sense - that is, everywhere the thing you will put in the completion handler is available. In this one there's two occurences of the handler, for example, to handle a boolean: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35314751/2227743

Comment: @EricD. thanks it looks working

Comment: Excellent! And you know what? It would be cool if you made an answer with the solution and the details of how we resolved this issue. An answer like this could help future visitors with an issue similar to yours. Just a suggestion, of course.

Comment: @EricD. Sure, but here I get something strange I don't know if it's come from the completion I get this: "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release."

Comment: Oh, that's because you're doing UI stuff in a background thread, and it should *never* happen. You have to modify the UI *on the main thread*. You know, like `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // do the UI work }`.